# Discord.js Bot help command doesn't work

Tags: node.js, bots, discord.js

I tried solving this problem for the past 2-3 days. When I type in chat !help, the command doesn't work and I receive this in the console:

```
(node:13264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.fields[0].name: This field is required
    at item.request.gen.end (C:\Users\alexx\Dropbox\Bot Try\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:71:65)
    at then (C:\Users\alexx\Dropbox\Bot Try\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
(node:13264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:13264) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The file that runs when help is run: https://pastebin.com/jMRjy7Dw
app.js: https://pastebin.com/PmVBKszM

Comment: Add `console.log(commands[cmd].name);` above line 25 and check if you're getting anything.. I think this may be blank hence the error "embed.fields[0].name: This field is required"

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the same error.

Comment: It's not a fix... It was to check if `commands[cmd].name` was blank, when you logged this did you get anything in console?

Comment: @newbie it gave the exact same error. Absolutely nothing changed.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, when I asked you to `console.log(commands[cmd].name);` you said that nothing came up in the console.

That means that you have tried to you tried to [`.addField()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=addField) using an empty `name` which will throw an error since the `name` is  not optional.

Also since [`<TextChannel>#send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) you should handle this promise rejection by using `.catch()`. In your case `.catch(console.error)` would show a more detailed error in your console. 
Here's an example to further clarify what I'm saying:

```
/* Here it is used correctly and will output an embed without any errors */
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
 .addField('test', '123');
message.channel.send(embed).catch(console.error);

/* Here it is used incorrectly and will throw an error similar to your case */
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
 .addField('', '123'); // as the name of the field is empty it will throw the error
message.channel.send(embed).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I check a few things and it seems if I specify User, Moderator, Administrator it works. Partially. Partially because at usage it shows something like this: Usage: [object Object]setPrefix <prefix>. When I leave help blank it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the first link you posted, I guess you should include brackets when "newing" an instance, that is:

```
const embed = (new Discord.RichEmbed()).setColor(0x1D82B6);
```

Comment: No. I tried even without .setColor and even as you said but no.